# Jenkins shows an error chrome not reachable

Tags: linux, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

When I execute the tests on Linux I get the below issue:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
(Session info: headless chrome=67.0.3396.99)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 
platform=Linux 4.14.33-51.34.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

These tests were working fine when executing through command line. I installed jenkins and set up few job and started executing the same tests using jenkin jobs. After setting up jenkins I get the above error and currently test execution through command line also shows the same error

Jenkins is installed as war file and started using the nohup command from a non root user.

Below is the code for web driver initialization

```
public static WebDriver getDriver(){

        //Get the current OS Version
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1920x1080");
        //Execute Headless if on Test Server
        if(os.contains("linux")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to chromedriver");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
            //Option added to resolve chrome not reachable issue
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-setuid-sandbox");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        }
        webdriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        return webdriver;
    }
```

This works without an issue on local machine running on Mac

Any help would be appreciated. Stuck with setting up Jenkins jobs due to this

When Jenkins is uninstalled the command line execution starts working fine again. Is it something to do with Jenkins installation?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
public static WebDriver getDriver(){
        //Get the current OS Version
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1920x1080");
        //Execute Headless if on Test Server
        if(os.contains("linux")) {
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to chromedriver");

        }
        webdriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        return webdriver;
    }
```

Comment: Tried with the above code and still no luck. Keep getting the same issue

Comment: is your chrome driver executable ?

Comment: also check path of chrome driver

Comment: Chrome driver is executable and the path is also correct. This was working fine earlier when executed through command line. The error started after installing Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the issue is with the resolution setup for headless chrome in chromeoptions in Linux and Jenkins. Pass diff resolution and results will vary. Tried with the following and now I am getting 100% accurate results.

```
    File file = new File("/usr/bin/chromedriver");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("headless");
    options.addArguments("window-size=1280x800");
    options.addArguments("no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("–disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    options.addArguments("--disable-setuid-sandbox");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```